# How do I make boundaries when inputting time?

Tags: c++, validation, time

I'm typing up a program right now and it requires me to input a departure and arrival time. How can I make it so that the input value has to be within 0:00 and 23:59?

Right now I have

```
cout << "\n\nEnter the departure time on the first day of the trip : ";
cin >> departure_Time;

cout << "\n\nEnter the arrival time on the last day of the trip : ";
cin >> arrival_Time;
```

and I want to make it so that they can't be a time outside of the boundaries.

Comment: that is not very much you have right now! what have you tried? what type's are departure_Time/arrival_Time...

Comment: sorry! i just copied the part that had to do with what i needed help with. They're going in as doubles

Comment: and how do you put it in? like 12.00? however, split hours and minutes and check if the values are in the ranges (0-23, 0-59).

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `while` loop to test if `departure_Time` and `arrival_Time` are within bounds. Then based on the result either move on to the rest of the program or redirect the user back to the start.

This can be implemented a multitude of ways. Without knowing how you plan to use the data and solely based on the code you provided this example should illustrate the idea of the `while` loops ability to check for invalid input.

```
int main()
{
    beginning:
    double departure_Time = 0.00, arrival_Time = 0.00;
    cout<<"\n\nEnter the departure time on the first day of the trip : ";
    cin>> departure_Time;
    cout<<"\n\nEnter the arrival time on the last day of the trip : ";
    cin>> arrival_Time;
    while (departure_Time < 0.00 || arrival_Time > 23.59) {
        cout<<"\n\nTry again...";
        cin.clear();
        cin.sync();
        goto beginning;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is just a quick implementation to illustrate the point. I hope it helps.